# Highcharts centre of a bubble chart point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to add some extra information to a bubble chart on point clicks, but for the life of me I can't find the centre of a bubble point!

Here's what's happening:
http://jsfiddle.net/H07R0D/Mktvz/

and here's the point click event

```
plotOptions: {
    bubble: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function() {
                    var renderer = this.series.chart.renderer;
                    var point = this.graphic;
                    var path = renderer.path(['M',point.cx,point.cy,'L',100,100])
                        .attr({
                            'stroke-width': 1,
                            stroke: 'red'
                         }).add();
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When a bubble is clicked, I'm trying to draw a path from the bubble's centre to an arbitrary point(just testing....) but the drawn path never starts in the bubble's centre.

Is there a different value other than point.cx and point.cy I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution :

```
var plotBox = point.renderer.plotBox;
var path = renderer.path(['M',point.cx+plotBox.x,point.cy+plotBox.y,'L',100,100])
```

In fact, your graphic does not start at 0,0 of your svg, it has an offset. You can find it in the renderer of every objects. Your graphic is contained into the plotBox.

I have updated your jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/FsDks/

Comment: My Fiddle was bad because I didn't paste the good link. thank you for the remark.

Comment: Ah, didn't know there was an offset beyond cx/cy.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use plotX and plotY coordinades, kept in point object (not graphic) and add plotTop / plotLeft (spacing around chart).

```
var renderer = this.series.chart.renderer,
                                chart = this.series.chart,
                                point = this,
                                path;


                            path = renderer.path(['M',point.plotX + chart.plotLeft,point.plotY + chart.plotTop,'L',100,100])
                                .attr({
                                    'stroke-width': 1,
                                    stroke: 'red'
                                }).add();                               
                            this.graphic.animate({                                  
                                opacity: 0.2                                    
                            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mktvz/4/

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect.  Gave Pierre the solution just on timeframe..  Again, thanks very much